# How can I enable logging for requests going through mod proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-proxy, debug

Is there a way to log requests going through mod proxy? I need a way to debug my configuration, because I don't seem to be getting where I should be. I need the following information:

- headers of incoming requests
- what is being sent to the proxy target

Maybe a related question: is there a way to strip some headers? I tried the following:

```
ProxyPass         /proxy/other http://not.under.my.control/
<Location /proxy/other>
   ProxyPassReverse /
   RequestHeader unset Authorization
</Location>
```

I don't really know whether this is ok, because I don't see anything.

Comment: I would use `mitmproxy` for this sort of debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option might be `mod_forensic`, can easily log the request and headers etc.
Beware of disk space usage though, on a heavy load web-site mod_forensic can easily produce tens of Gigs per day.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_forensic.html

Comment: From my own experience, `mod_forensic` will log all http headers but not the payload (eg: the data assoicated to a POST)

Answer (score 18):

## Try dumpio

I used dumpio. I put the following in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/dumpio.conf`:

```
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so

DumpIOInput On
DumpIOOutput On
DumpIOLogLevel debug

LogLevel debug
```

An often forgotten piece is setting the `LogLevel` to `debug`. Without it, you won't actually see any DumpIO output.

The log output is written to the error log for the virtual host and/or the server.

Comment: It turned out pretty helpful for me. Thanks!

On Ubuntu I went `$ a2enmode dump_io`
After that I've added lines from the answer to a VirtualHost directive.
Checked out the `$ tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` while making requests and got all the info I needed.
After you're done with debugging it's better to turn it off by `$ a2dismode dump_io` and reverting the VirtualHost. Otherwise you'll get very bloated logs.

Comment: The directive "DumpIOLogLevel" no longer exists. One has to set `LogLevel dumpio:trace7` as described in [mod_dumpio](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dumpio.html)

Answer (score 12):

You can also append `proxy:trace5` to your existing `LogLevel` directive

If you have this

```
LogLevel error
```

Change it to this

```
LogLevel error proxy:trace5
```

**Be sure to change that back to normal after use. This will create huge log files fast.**

Comment: This doesn't work for apache 2.2, which this question is tagged as.

Answer (score 6):

If you change LogLevel to debug it'll give you more detail about what's going on in the standard Error log.

```
LogLevel debug
```

That'll get you plenty of information about what's happening.

Comment: Although I now have quite a bit of additional information on the proxy in the log, the information I would like to see is not there. Using LogFormat, can we somehow get the information I requested?

Comment: Have a play around with LogFormat, Note that you can use mod_forensic and mod_security to get much more details

Comment: In apache 2.4 the LogLevel directive is in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` on Ubuntu. Seems obvious but it took me a second to figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

mod_security can log request body & headers, among other things. [Link](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/07-logging.html)

Comment: Best practice is to provide a concise summary.  As of 2015-08, the link seems dead...

Answer (score -2):

You can use these logs, but they won't give you exactly what you want :

```
<VirtualHost yourdomain.com> 
    Customlog yourdomain.com-access.log combined 
    ErrorLog yourdomain.com-error.log
# Your other stuff
</VirtualHost>
```