# Apache proxypass exclude rule being ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass

I've been scratching my head on this for far too long.

I have what I consider a simple configuration using the proxypass rules for Apache, I want to supply a list of exclusions before using a 'catchall' rule to redirect all traffic to a local node server.

The setup follows:

```
ProxyPass        /contact-us !
ProxyPass        / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

The result of the above configuration is that `/contact-us` is sent to node (`localhost:3000`), as I understand the documentation it should be ignored. If I set a destination for `/contact-us` then the request is correctly handled and the proxied content is returned.

Am I missing something? Does adding the catchall (`/`) to the ruleset change the behaviour?

Edit: Added rest of file for reference

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  dev.site.com
    ServerAdmin admin@dev.site.com

    ProxyPass        /contact-us !
    ProxyPass        / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public
    <Directory /var/www/site/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(dev\.site\.com)$"  origin_is=$0

        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true env=origin_is
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.site.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.site.com-access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.site.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.site.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your config. For example, do you have those in a location block or not?

Comment: @ColtonCat - thanks for your reply, no these are the only `proxypass` rules for the virtualhost, as I understand it, any rules within a location directive are resolved before these are, so I made sure that wasn't the case. The rest of the configuration is quite vanilla, I'll add it to the OP.

Comment: The documentation talks about directories excluded maybe that is the catch. Maybe you should try `SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/contact-us$ no-proxy=1`

Comment: That looks like a correct configuration, but that may be impacted by additional directives in an `.htaccess`  file in either the DocumentRoot `/var/www/site/public` or the   `/var/www/site/public/contact-us/` sub directory

Comment: @user188737 - nice find, that is one thing I hadn't tried, unfortunately after updating Apache to use it (Req. 2.4.26), it didn't help, I'm glad to have tried something new though, thanks. 

@HBruijn Hmm, there are a few application specific rewrite rules in the top level `.htaccess`, I'll try cleaning those up just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue and you were right @HBruijn.

I am running the Laravel framework on the virtualhost which means requests are directed to `/index.php` to be routed, so after the first rule succeeded (`/contact-us !`) the request was rewritten to `/index.php` which was then being proxied in the catch all rule.

I was able to add an exclude rule for (`/index.php`), and also the following Fpm request (see the log below) to solve my problem. This solution may not be possible for everyone.

I was able to unravel this thanks to this comment by @yunzen - https://serverfault.com/a/895673, by adding `LogLevel error proxy:trace5` I was able to see the following:

```
[Mon Mar 04 04:39:56.876129 2019] [proxy:trace2] [pid 5564] mod_proxy.c(683): [client 220.244.99.86:51059] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/contact-us' against prefix '/index.php' for proxying
[Mon Mar 04 04:39:56.876170 2019] [proxy:trace2] [pid 5564] mod_proxy.c(683): [client 220.244.99.86:51059] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/contact-us' against prefix '/contact-us' for proxying
[Mon Mar 04 04:39:56.876174 2019] [proxy:trace1] [pid 5564] mod_proxy.c(736): [client 220.244.99.86:51059] AH03463: proxying is explicitly disabled for URI path '/contact-us'; declining
[Mon Mar 04 04:39:56.876880 2019] [proxy:trace2] [pid 5564] mod_proxy.c(683): [client 220.244.99.86:51059] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/index.php' against prefix '/index.php' for proxying
[Mon Mar 04 04:39:56.876890 2019] [proxy:trace1] [pid 5564] mod_proxy.c(736): [client 220.244.99.86:51059] AH03463: proxying is explicitly disabled for URI path '/index.php'; declining
[Mon Mar 04 04:39:56.876936 2019] [proxy:trace2] [pid 5564] mod_proxy.c(683): [client 220.244.99.86:51059] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/php72-fcgi-www/index.php' against prefix '/index.php' for proxying
```

Note the context changes from this single request.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a little comment in the docs for Apache (2.4.26 and higher only) it is possible to use `no-proxy` environment variable for proxy exclusions.

It gets ugly however when you need an internal rewrite to serve your excluded page, because then the ProxyPass exclusions and just setting the `no-proxy` variable based on REQUEST_URI has no effect, because REQUEST_URI changes after the internal rewrite and the ProxyPass is evaluated again and the environment variable is only visible as `REDIRECT_no-proxy` not as `no-proxy`.

We can use a little subterfuge here, and this will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/contact-us$ - [E=no-proxy:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_no-proxy} .+
RewriteRule .* - [E=no-proxy:1]
```

If you put this in the Virtual Host section it will work. If you put it in the Directory section, it won't because then ProxyPass is already acted upon.

Comment: Hmm ugly, but may be less ugly than my solution, I will try this shortly and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It is dead ugly. I was quite surprised actually that Request_URI of SetEnvIf moves with rewrite. Up till now I always believed it reflected the original request. And have been working with Apache for something like 15 years. The advantage of this is that you also proxy the direct /index.php?id= type of requests, which would otherwise stay on the origin server.